# Android. Fix the height of a fragment on all screens

Tags: android, fragment, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_relative_imagen_poli"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Pink">

    <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_imgfoto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
   android:src="@drawable/pol_alza" />

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_nombre_encima_de_imagen"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:text="ESTO ES EL NOMBRE DEL POLIDEPORTIVO"/>

     <fragment
   android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_map"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="130dp"
   android:layout_below="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_imgfoto"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_titulo_direccion"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_map"
   android:text="@string/titulo_direccion"
   android:textSize="15dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <TextView
   android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_tv_direccion"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_titulo_direccion"
   android:text="Direccion"
   android:textSize="15dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

 <TextView
   android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_titulo_telefono"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_tv_direccion"
   android:text="@string/titulo_telefono"
   android:textSize="15dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_tv_telefono"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_titulo_telefono"
   android:text="Telefono"
   android:textSize="15dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_titulo_email"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_tv_telefono"
   android:text="@string/titulo_email"
   android:textSize="15dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_tv_nombre"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_titulo_email"
   android:text="Nombre"
   android:textSize="15dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

I want this result.

[image]

In Nexus 4 and samsung S5 it is OK. But small screen not.

[image]

In my opinion the error is in:

```
 <fragment
android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="130dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_imgfoto"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

specifically in the height, but I did not fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: You could use weight

Comment: I tried that but not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split up the view into smaller sections using Layouts and than remove the 130dp height and use weight instead.

Comment: Depending on how you want to position your elements you could choose different layouts. Like all the TextViews on the bottom could go into one LinearLayout.

Comment: Thank You @SergeNassar

This is the solution:
[code](http://pastebin.com/XKPhxCdz)